# Смена VDS в зависимости от региона

Tags: apache, nginx, route

Приветствую!

Допустим, у меня есть **2 VDS**, с айпи :

127.1.1.1.1
127.1.1.1.2

Допустим, я зашел из Европы, то мой сайт обращается к IP 127.1.1.1.1, если из Америки - 127.1.1.1.2, как реализовать такое?

Типичный пример - **VKontakte**

У них, если заходить из России, то айпи один, если из Германии, айпи другой

Comment: Где вопрос-то, собственно?

Comment: Как так сделать?

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос так, чтобы было полностью понятно, чего вы хотите. В комментариях не стоит объяснять, нужно чтобы ваш вопрос был самодостаточен.

Comment: Готово, дополнил

Comment: По-моему, то что вы хотите, называется geoDNS.